# Search words in array based on few words

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

Hi I have a problem how to search for words containing at least part of a word. What I mean words that have word I find in array javascript without built-in function except only PUSH.

This task requires no index.of, slice, substr, substring, regex etc. Only PUSH

This my code so far:

```
function wordsChecker(sentences, search) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        var isCheck = false
        for (var j = 0; j < sentences.length; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < search.length; k++) {
                if (sentences[i][j] == search[k]) {
                    isCheck = true
                }
            }
        }
        if (isCheck == true) {
            result.push(sentences[i])
        }
    }
    return result
}

console.log(wordsChecker(['broom, room, rox, show room, stroom, root, rote, brother'], 'roo'))

//expected output : [broom, room, show room, stroom, root]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mind explaining why you have 3 loops in there for a single array?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `push` is not a good method for finding something from an array, since it doesn't read from the array, and returns only the index of the newly-pushed member.

Comment: Just use something along the lines of `for(var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {if(sentences[i].contains(search){return true}else{return false}}`

Comment: You are passing an array with a single string. Is that what you meant to do, or should `sentences` be an array with several value? As it is, you need to split that string if I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: a nested iteration, i.e., on each iteration of the findWords array, iterate over the targetArray.

Comment: @SimonHyll i tried to solve it index by index

Comment: @Cristol.GdM my question is how to solve this code with only use push

Comment: @MarkMeyer I can solve this with index of but my lecture wants me to do it just with push

Comment: @AndyWarhol You already have some code, what is not working with it? Do you get wrong results, it doesn't run?

Comment: @Cristol.GdM Yes, it was until I recode and now finally I understand how to solve this. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the first you should make correct array. I hope this code work for you

```js
function wordsChecker(sentences, search) {
    var result = [], k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
        var isCheck = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < sentences[i].length; j++) {
            while (k < search.length) {
                if (sentences[i][j] == search[k]) {
                    isCheck = true;
                    k++;
                    break;
                } 
                else {
                  isCheck = false;
                  k = 0;
                  break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isCheck === true && k === search.length) {
            result.push(sentences[i]);
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(wordsChecker(['broom', 'room', 'rox', 'show room', 'stroom', 'root', 'rote', 'brother'], 'roo'));
```

Comment: thanks bro, but I solved this 2 days ago. But I like the way you code.